# Mongo Java Driver ObjectId.getCounter() is Deprecated

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I need to use the **"getCounter()"** method of the **"ObjectId"** object but currently it finds Deprecated and I can't use that method to cover sonarqube coverage, is there any method that replaces "getCounter ()"?

```java
ObjectId objectId= new ObjectId(idMongo);
int counter = objectId.getCounter();
```

method in the ObjectId class

```java
  /** @deprecated */
  @Deprecated
  public int getCounter() {
    return this.counter;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the specification for ObjectID format found [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/objectid.rst)

> Drivers MUST NOT have an accessor method on an ObjectID class for
>   obtaining this value.

The specification is to align the number generation with servers and drivers.

in version 4.0 they will remove the method completely.

**So the answer to your question is no.**